# Prestashop slowdown after gzip enabling

Tags: php, performance, .htaccess, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've got some really painful problem with my Prestashop installation. I was trying to "score more points" in google PageSpeed Insights and I enabled a gzip compression for files. It turn out to be a bad idea - suddenly TTFB increased to 4-5 s while at the beginning it was only 0.5 - 1 s.
I turn off gzip compression and regenerate .htaccess but TTFB didn't back to normal.

I add some dump from debugging.

```
Load Time   2547 ms - You'd better run your shop on a toaster
Querying Time   74 ms
Queries 178
Memory Peak Usage   33.1 Mb
Included Files  225 files - 3.52 Mb
PrestaShop Cache    0.01 Mb
Global vars 0.62 Mb
PrestaShop Version  1.6.1.6
PHP Version 5.6.18 (OK)
MySQL Version   5.6.27-log (OK)
Memory Limit    512M
Max Execution Time  300s
Smarty Cache    enabled
Smarty Compilation  auto

 Time   Cumulated Time  Memory Usage    Memory Peak Usage
config  201 ms  201 ms  9.08 Mb 9.22 Mb
__construct 0 ms    201 ms  - Mb    9.22 Mb
init        55 ms   256 ms  4.24 Mb 13.43 Mb
checkAccess 0 ms    256 ms  - Mb    13.43 Mb
setMedia    76 ms   332 ms  0.27 Mb 13.70 Mb
postProcess 0 ms    332 ms  - Mb    13.70 Mb
initHeader  0 ms    332 ms  0.01 Mb 13.70 Mb
initContent 1548 ms 1880 ms 16.96 Mb    30.89 Mb
initFooter  257 ms  2137 ms 1.25 Mb 32.07 Mb
display     410 ms  2547 ms 0.77 Mb 33.05 Mb


Hook                        Time    Memory Usage
__construct                 421 ms  9.50 Mb
hookHeader                  239 ms  - Mb
hooktop                     230 ms  6.75 Mb
hookfooter                  193 ms  0.25 Mb
hookdisplayHomeTabContent   169 ms  0.75 Mb
hookdisplayHomeTab          136 ms  - Mb
hookdisplayHeader           134 ms  - Mb
hookdisplayHome             87 ms   0.25 Mb
hookdisplayNav              75 ms   0.25 Mb
hookdisplayTop              38 ms   - Mb
hookhome                    36 ms   - Mb
hookdisplayTopColumn        34 ms   - Mb
hookdisplayFooter           31 ms   - Mb
13 hooks                    1823 ms 17.75 Mb

Module              Time    Memory Usage
blockcart           235 ms  6.75 Mb
homefeatured        100 ms  0.25 Mb
blocknewproducts    98 ms   0.75 Mb
blockbestsellers    91 ms   0.50 Mb
blockspecials       89 ms   - Mb
homeslider          89 ms   0.25 Mb
blocksearch         78 ms   - Mb
blockcategories     71 ms   0.25 Mb
blocktopmenu        71 ms   0.25 Mb
editorial           69 ms   0.25 Mb
blockcms            63 ms   0.25 Mb
cssmodule           61 ms   - Mb
blockfacebook       53 ms   0.25 Mb
blockcontactinfos   53 ms   - Mb
blockcontact        53 ms   0.25 Mb
blockmyaccountfooter50 ms   0.25 Mb
themeconfigurator   49 ms   0.50 Mb
blocksocial         42 ms   0.25 Mb
blockuserinfo       42 ms   - Mb
blocknewsletter     42 ms   1.75 Mb
blockcmsinfo        41 ms   0.25 Mb
blocklanguages      33 ms   0.25 Mb
ganalytics          33 ms   0.25 Mb
uecookie            20 ms   0.25 Mb
blockpaymentlogo    18 ms   - Mb
twengabid           18 ms   0.25 Mb
statsdata           18 ms   0.25 Mb
easymarketing       16 ms   0.75 Mb
blockmyaccount      16 ms   0.25 Mb
blockcurrencies     15 ms   - Mb
blocktags           15 ms   - Mb
blockviewed         15 ms   - Mb
blockstore          14 ms   - Mb
blocklayered        13 ms   1.50 Mb
socialsharing       13 ms   0.25 Mb 
productscategory    11 ms   0.25 Mb
sekeywords          10 ms   0.25 b
pagesnotfound       7 ms    0.25 Mb
38 modules          1823 ms 17.75Mb
```

As You can see, it looks like whole computations are running slower. Yup I have cache, "don't compile template", CCC and memcache enabled. I also tried to run PHP 7. Without any effects. Shop is fairly small - just a few products, few images, few clients. Do you have any idea how I could fix it? I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but a max execution time of 300s looks very high for a production site, did you deliberately set this value ?

Comment: Did you try to decrease gzip compression level ?

Comment: I dont think gzip is the culprit here. I've only had bad experiences with prestashop's cache feature. Try disabling it (not smarty cache)

Comment: @berty This is a default timeout value at my host. I haven't changed it yet. I didn't try to decrease compression level - I realized that in my case gziping in unnecessary and I turn it off.

Comment: @defuzed I've tried all configurations... Cache on, cache off, template compilation always, never etc. I didn't notice any significant change.

Comment: are we talking about the same cache? I don't mean the cache section of the "Smarty" tab, I mean the last part of the "performance" section -> "caching" did you try disabling that?

Comment: @defuzed yes we are talking about same cache - at the bottom, with options such as PHP::Memcache or file system. As I said - disabling this doesn't show any difference.